# Java generics. Type mismatch: cannot convert from object to

Tags: java, generics

I have the following generic Java class:

```
class A<T> {
    List<A> list;

    List<A> getList() {
        return list;
    }
}
```

When I try to get the first element of the list

```
A a = new A();
A b = a.getList().get(0);
```

I have the compiler error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to A
```

If I introduce an intermediary list:

```
A a = new A();
List<A> sameList = a.getList();
A b = sameList.get(0);
```

the error disappears, but the warning appears:

```
Type safety: The expression of type List needs unchecked conversion to conform to List<A>
```

The variable `sameList` has the same type as the method `getList()`. I am ready to put up with it, but I want to understand the reason. Why is there is a conversion?

Comment: `List<A>` uses the raw type of `A`, so the `List` on the inside is converted to the raw type `List`

Comment: You've used the raw version of A, you need `new A<A>` for an A that itself returns As. although the list inside A also looks wrong

Comment: You have a class that uses a raw type, so you have to instanciate it with this raw type `A<SomeClass> a = new A<SomeClass>();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the fun parts about raw types. Not only do you not get generic checks on the raw type itself, but it also causes generic checks for *all interacting code* to be skipped too.

Thus, when you use the raw type `A`, the `List<A>` you defined inside `A` is actually erased to `List`, so that `getList` returns a raw type `List`, and `get(0)` would return an `Object`.

This is also why you get an "unchecked conversion" warning. `getList()` returns a `List`, not a `List<A>`. So assigning a raw type `List` to a `List<A>` will produce an unchecked conversion warning.

> The variable sameList has the same type as the method `getList()`

So you're actually wrong, here. `sameList` has a *different* type as the return type of `getList()` for the raw type `A`.

To solve this you'll need to parameterize all uses of `A` in your code.

Comment: Thanks! I understood that I need to read more about generics. If I just declare "A<A> a = new A()", the converison doesn't appear. Honestly, it breaks my brain.

Comment: @user3803250 Yeah, generics has quite a few corner cases that take some time to get. Interesting that using a raw type for the parameter solves it... Looks like *I* still have some more reading to do. Can't blame you for your confusion...